# Advanced Custom Fields Plugin Conditional Logic

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the ACF Plugin (advancedcustomfields.com) for WordPress to give admins some more control.

I have a repeater field setup, which will allow for two sub-fields. 1. Image 2. Link. The link will either go to a URL or a Page / Post.

I am able to do this individually, but I need the option to do one or the other.

When setting up ACF's conditional logic, I can give the admin the option to select either a URL or to link to a page / post (from a drop down)

The problem I am running into, is that I cannot **display the proper sub_field** depending on their selection.

The documentation helped out a lot with all of the other questions I had. But this one is a bit out of my league.

Any help would be appreciated.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/code-examples/

Comment: Do you have code sample of what you have tried?

Comment: If you're using conditional logic, you must have set up a field where the user selects URL or page link. Can't you just use get_sub_field() on that field to check which option they selected?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you're using a radio button to choose between URL and Page/Post Dropdown Selector

In your php code where you'll build out the href for the link do something like this:

```
<?php if(get_sub_field('link-type')=='url'){
    $myURL = get_sub_field('url-field');
}elseif (get_sub_field('link-type')=='page-post'{
    $myURL = get_sub_field('page-post-selector');
}?>
<a href="<?php echo $myURL; ?>"></a>
```

This checks the value of your sub_field "link-type" and if it is "url" it uses the "url-field" field, and if it is "page-post" it uses the "page-post-selector" field.